# JSON syntax to set custom date field with current date/time using a civirules action

Tags: civirules, participants

In a civirules action I would like to set a custom participant field to the current date/time using the action 'Set Custom Field on any entity'

What json can I use for current date/time to set a custom date?
(or might there be another smart workaround)

> $now() does not do the job

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This exact thing came up for me this week.

Just use the word "now", without quotes. No json.

It uses api3 to set the value so anything api3 understands will work.

Comment: YES! thank you, been looking for this answer for months.